# Закрытие потоков c#

Tags: c#

народ, при закрытии потока зависает программа, никакого исключения не выдает, try не помогает, подскажите в чем проблема? 
пробовал и Abort() и Join().

Comment: вот, поток мне нужно завершить, но чтобы программа при этом не зависала

Answer (score 1):

`Join` - это не закрытие потока. Это ожидание завершения потока.

`Abort` - это прерывание потока.

Если Вы пытаетесь ждать завершения текущего потока, Вы неминуемо зависнете навечно - Вы попадаете в состояние, когда поток ждёт, когда он сам завершится, но он не завершается, потому что занят тем, что ждёт.

Прервать текущий поток - по идее, тоже странное действие.

А если делать это с другими потоками - проблем быть не должно. Единственное, с чем могут быть проблемы, - это если поток ожидает ответа от вызова неуправляемого кода. В этом случае `Abort` не сработает до тех пор, пока вызов не вернёт управление.

Answer (score 1):

Задайте потоку свойство [`IsBackground`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground(v=vs.110).aspx) перед тем как запустить его. В таком случае  он завершиться при завершении основного потока. Небольшой пример:

```
...
Thread MyThread1 = new Thread(MyFunc);
MyThread1.IsBackground = true;
MyThread1.Start();
...
```